# To get the name from input file type and display in a p tag through javascript.

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am trying to get the name from input file type to display the name in a p tag, below is my code, advance thanx to all.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var path = document.getElementById("photo").value;
var filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = filename;
</script>


<input type="file" id="photo"/>
<p id="log"></p>
```

Comment: What's not working? Are you getting any errors? Where is "photo" declared?

Comment: You code seems to be good. What not working ?

Comment: not getting the input file name in `<p id="log"></p>` tag.

Comment: If that's the actual code you have, you don't get any output because the input field is empty when the code runs at page load. You need to attach it to an event, like clicking a button.

Comment: juhana is right and if you have done that and you want to get a only file name without extinction then use it path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf("."));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code...

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Usv9Y/3/)

```
    var input = document.getElementById("photo");

input.onclick = function () {
    this.value = null;
};

input.onchange = function () {
    var path = input.value;
    var filename = "";
    if(path.lastIndexOf("\\") != -1)
        filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,path.length);
    else
        filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,path.length);
    document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = filename;
};
```

Comment: thank you so much Nikhil for your help, and also thanks to Benjamin Warren, Hariharan, Juhana for their comments.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you's trying to get the name of the file. Below is the code of doing that:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
function showfile()
{
var path = document.getElementById("photo").value;
var filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = filename;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>


<input type="file" id="photo" onchange="showfile()"/>
<p id="log"></p>
</body>
</html>
```